# Índices desnecessários no banco são um problema?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, índices

Costuma-se adicionar índices para melhorar o desempenho das consultas. Porém normalmente não se recomenda sair adicionando índices em tudo quanto é coluna, apenas onde se identificar a necessidade.

Por que dessa recomendação? Que tipo de problemas índices desnecessários podem causar?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Basicamente é porque **cada novo índice exige mais tempo para atualizar** o banco em qualquer alteração que afete estes índices. Já vi gente sugerir fazer índices para tudo. Com apenas 6 ou 7 campos, para todas as combinações são necessários dezenas para centenas de índices e todos precisariam ser atualizados mesmo que altere apenas um campo. O tempo gasto pode afetar a escalabilidade do banco.

Em alguns casos a consulta pode ser prejudicada também. O **espaço ocupado prejudicará o cache** dos dados/índices que realmente são importantes. Além disto acessar primeiro o índice para depois acessar o dado tem um custo e ele pode ser maior que acessar os dados diretamente em certos padrões. E nem sempre o otimizador do sistema detecta corretamente se ele deve fazer o acesso direto.

Da mesma forma as recomendações automáticas dos sistemas SGDBs para criar índices nem sempre são corretas.

Além disto cada novo índice é um **recurso a mais para dar manutenção**. Viola o [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Inclusive dificulta *upgrades* no modelo de uma base de dados no sistema em produção.

Já vi "especialistas conceituados" dizerem que o ideal é criar índice para tudo e ir tirando os que não precisam. Não consigo imaginar como isto possa fazer sentido. É o pior caso de otimização prematura que já vi. Toda otimização deve ser criada quando você mediu e ficou claro que ela é necessária. Índice existe fundamentalmente para otimizar acesso aos dados.

Os sistemas de banco de dados mais completos possuem muitos recursos para obter as informações necessárias para a decisão correta. Estas informações podem ajudar a identificar índices desnecessários também. E como é um recurso para otimizar é preciso revisar com frequência, o que pode ser bom em um momento pode não ser mais no futuro.

Um exemplo típico de erro em criação de índice é quando ele é usado exclusivamente para geração de relatórios esporádicos. A perda para gerar um relatório esporádico sem a otimização do índice costuma causar menos prejuízo que o índice causará no sistema como um todo.

Mas um dos piores exageros que já vi, e acontece muito, é criar um índice para `colA+colB` e outro para `colA`. O primeiro pode ser usado para obter a mesma otimização que o segundo provê, tornando-o desnecessário.

Mas algo que preciso ressaltar sempre: medir é o mais importante. Eu e mesmo profissionais bem mais experientes que eu no assunto vivem tendo surpresas. O que parece ajudar muitas vezes prejudica mais.

[Boa referência](https://use-the-index-luke.com/).

---

Para evitar entendimento errado da outra resposta (que foi removida mas acho que a informação ainda é relevante) pelas pessoas que estão aprendendo sobre o assunto vou colocar alguns pontos:

- A perda de performance causada pela criação de índices desnecessários se dá em **qualquer** operação que altere um dado contido nas chaves do índice. Não importa se é `INSERT`, `UPDATE` e até mesmo `DELETE` dependendo da implementação. Alterações que não afetam a chave do índice não causam problemas de performance. Em sistemas de banco de dados que usam alguma forma de [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) qualquer alteração acaba afetando pelo menos o índice da chave primária (que talvez seja [clusterizado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Clustered)) já que o dado é copiado para outro local.
- A performance do `SELECT` também pode ser afetada negativamente conforme citado acima na minha resposta. Não ocorre com frequência, principalmente porque o planejador costuma evitar o uso do índice nestes casos, mas **pode**.
- Já a criação do índice beneficia qualquer operação de acesso aos dados que o planejador do banco de dados identifique que seja útil. Normalmente isto ocorre em comparações do `WHERE` mas não em qualquer comparação (isto é importante). Há casos que o índice não ajuda. Índice não é mágico, ele tem uma organização que otimizam algumas relações, não todas. Ocorre também quando se usa `ORDER BY`, `JOIN` e em quando há uso de algumas funções agregadoras. Mas é bom ficar claro que só uma medição pode garantir que haverá ganho. É claro que a experiência pode fazer o desenvolvedor do banco de dados identificar casos simples, mas é preciso ter cuidado. O bom nadador costuma se arriscar e morrer afogado mais que o nadador que tem medo de água desconhecida. Regras gerais, como sempre, podem causar mais mal do que bem. Sempre tem que analisar o caso específico com informações específicas para o caso.

  Exemplos onde o índice provavelmente não vai ajudar: `WHERE colA = colB / 2` ou `WHERE colA LIKE '%Silva%'`.
- De qualquer forma o ganho ocorre em qualquer das operações de acesso aos dados que tenha algum uso das cláusulas acima. Claro que em `UPDATE` e `DELETE` apenas o `WHERE` e o `ORDER BY` é relevante.

Está cheio de mitos em desenvolvimento de software e como consequência temos muitos softwares com problemas porque há a leitura de informações ilusórias sobre os assuntos. Deixar margem para entendimento errado causa mais mal do que bem.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Queria entender os negativos. O que tem errado na resposta?

Comment: deve ser alguém com preguiça de ler...

Comment: @bigown Temos dois criadores de indices desnecessários no site (devem ser do pessoal das _boas práticas_ :D )

Comment: Para relatórios que usam muitos `where`'s seria interessante usar algum software de indexação como o ElasticSearch para buscar por exemplo, nome, email, telefone, data inicial, data final. Então pegar os IDs desses documentos (que são os IDs no banco de dados) e posteriormente fazer uma consulta passando somente estes IDs usando `WHERE id IN (1,2,3,7,9,N...)` ? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77529/usando-elasticsearch-para-fazer-buscas-complexas-e-depois-pegar-os-ids-para-cons

Comment: @bigown Sua citação "um índice para `colA+colB` e outro para `colA`", pelo menos para `Postgresql` vale para o `WHERE colA = 1 AND colB=2` mas não para `WHERE colA = 1 OR colB=2`, no segundo caso o índice criado separadamente para `colA` será usado.
(primeira linha do link)
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html
No mais, muito boa resposta. +1

Comment: @TiagoOliveiradeFreitas alguns banco de dados fazem algumas otimizações extras mesmo.