# Índices em consultas no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, otimização, índices

Utilizar índices em consultas mysql realmente faz o resultado vir rapidamente para algumas consultas ou tabelas grandes.

Por exemplo na consulta abaixo:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 1;
```

Para uma tabela com 1 milhão registros se eu der o comando abaixo:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE status = 1;
```

Essa consulta demora muito. Então crie o índice para a coluna status e consegui remover 700 mil linhas rapidamente (coisa de 0.8s)

No select do exemplo eu não coloquei o `use index xyz` mas o banco de dados foi inteligente em usar o índice que crie para a coluna.

Mas e para consultas com vários  WHERE? Algo como

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 1 AND account = 12 AND data > '2014-09-09 00:00:00';
```

Se eu criar um índice com as colunas status, account e data o MYSQL vai usar na consulta acima de forma automática ou vou ter que colocar de forma explícita o `use index xpto`?

**UPDATE**

Depois de implementar somente um índice em uma tabela que tinha uma query complicada. Olha só o que resultou no uso de CPU no meu RDS na Amazon.

[image: Desempenho RDS Amazon]

Vou até poder diminuir o tipo de instância :D

Exemplo de criação de índice para o exemplo da query acima:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `status_idx` (`status`);
```

Comment: Se você adicionou um índice referente a coluna status, então automaticamente o Mysql usará este índice.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Para esta *query* específica vai utilizar o índice se existir um índice apropriado para ela. Este índice deverá incluir as colunas `status`, `account` e `data`. De preferência nesta ordem. Não há porque o MySQL não usar o índice automaticamente. De qualquer forma para ter certeza crie e veja o que acontece. Nem sempre o que deduzimos está correto.

Assim o índice classificará o `status` crescentemente, então ele poderá achar rápido as linhas com possuem o valor `1`. Em seguida ele poderá achar rápido as linhas que possuem o valor `12` para `account`, **dentre as linhas já selecionadas que satisfaça a condição anterior**. E finalmente selecionará todas as datas acima do valor indicado na *query*, novamente entre as linhas já selecionadas anteriormente nas condições anteriores. Obviamente que esta seleção não considerará outras faixas de dados que não contém os valores anteriores.

Note que precisa haver uma faixa única de seleção para aproveitar o índice por completo na *query*. Por isto a ordem pode ser importante para determinar se dá ou não para usar o índice. Por isso eu disse que nesta *query* específica o índice com a composição indicada seria usado. Uma outra *query* pode não conseguir usar o índice ou pode usar parcialmente para selecionar uma faixa através dele e o resto da seleção ter que ser varrendo o banco de dados linha por linha entre as linhas já selecionadas no índice.

Normalmente o segredo é ter índices que atendem as principais *queries* e evitar *queries* que não possam se beneficiar dos índices.

Os índices funcionam bem quando você consegue montar sub-faixas com eles. Em uma *query* muito complexa, que dificulte pegar estas sub-faixas não há índice que resolva. Aí o ideal é tentar pelo menos reduzir bastante as linhas que foram obtidas através do índice e deixar pouco para a seleção final.

Para tentar facilitar o entendimento, pense em como funciona esta busca. Quando você tem algo ordenado de acordo com o que você quer buscar fica fácil achar através de uma busca binária que tem uma complexidade logarítmica O(log n), ou seja, ela **divide e conquista**. Mesmo com bilhões de linhas, em pouco mais de 30 passos ele acha o que você quer. Quando não tem ordem alguma, o jeito é olhar um por um, complexidade linear O(n). Se a *query* olha para várias colunas ela vai tentar usar o primeiro método e fazer uma seleção bem rápida. Quando não for mais possível, apenas entre as linhas que já conseguiu selecionar rápido ele vai aplicar a condição determinada individualmente linha por linha. [Para entender um pouco mais sobre Big O leia essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33330/101).

Quando o otimizador não usa um índice existente é porque ele não conseguiu montar uma forma de "entender" sua *query* apropriadamente para o índice. Isto pode ser culpa da forma como o índice está montado ou pode ser porque o otimizador não é tão bom. Quase sempre o otimizador faz bem o seu serviço.

Na verdade pode ser que o índice não seja usado mesmo que tenha uma chave adequada. Há volumes de dados pequenos que a busca direta nos dados tenha um custo menor. O otimizador pode identificar que mesmo que ele possa selecionar sub-faixas, a análise subsequente pode ser tão custosa que eliminando a consulta ao índice pode trazer um resultado melhor. Mas nestes casos o otimizador renunciou seu uso de forma "consciente" para o seu benefício. Não dá para achar ruim. Apesar que há casos que ele erra.

Mas cuidado para não criar [índices demais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23360/101). As atualizações a eles podem tornar o software bem lento.

O que o AP fez na edição da pergunta é exatamente o que precisa ser feito. Tentar e ver o que realmente acontece. Com uma chave simples utilizando apenas a coluna mais relevante ele conseguiu um ganho enorme. Ele utilizou a coluna `status`. Não sei se ele tentou, mas poderia experimentar só com a coluna `account`, só com a coluna `data`, e fazer as combinações possíveis entre as três colunas e ver como fica cada resultado. Como o ganho parece ser fundamental, vale o pequeno esforço.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela aula. Vai me ajudar muito. Não sabia que a ordem das condicionais poderia influenciar a velocidade de uma consulta. Eu tive um grande ganho em velocidade somente criando um índice para um das colunas de uma query com várias condicionais.

Comment: @rodrigoum **pode** não quer dizer que influencie sempre. Depende do trabalho do otimizador. Ele pode mudar a ordem por conta própria se ele tiver certeza que o resultado será o mesmo. De fato criando índice para uma coluna já torna o conjunto total de linhas bem menor e melhora muito a performance. Muitas vezes pode ser tudo o que você precisa. Em outros casos, precisa ter todas as colunas para chegar em um bom resultado. É aquilo que eu falei, se tiver um conjunto pequeno para selecionar, a busca direta nos dados funciona melhor que o índice. O otimizador sabe disto.

Comment: bigown, olha que resultou a criação de um índice somente. Mais uma vez obrigado :D

Comment: @rodrigoum Muito legal. Imagino que o pico foi a criação do índice. Nada substitui um teste real. Você pode, se não fez, testar outras possibilidades de índice e ver o que acontece. Pode até piorar, mas só testando para saber. É bom saber que esta situação pode mudar no futuro com uma composição de dados diferente da atual. Embora eu imagino que para este caso específico, isso provavelmente não mudará muito. Se puder, para completar, coloque como ficou seu índice, assim ajuda de forma mais clara para outras pessoas.

Comment: Na verdade a dúvida foi mais conceitual. Acabei criando o índice em outra tabela aqui no meu sistema. Vou editar a pergunta colocando um exemplo de criação de índice para o exemplo que dei.