# Melhorar performance na busca quando não houver registro

Tags: postgresql, desempenho

Tenho um banco de dados com 9551011 linhas. Que contém endereços de todo o país.

Quando faço uma consulta por determinado lugar, e aquele endereço existe no banco, consigo ter um retorno em no máximo 2 segundos. O problema, é que esse banco é usado em uma aplicação onde a pessoa tem que subir um arquivo com vários endereços, e muitos desses endereços não exitem no banco. Quando um endereço não existe, ele demora MUITO naquela busca... Existe alguma maneira de melhorar isso? Já tentei com algumas formas de performance clássicas no mundo Postgresql como o Vacuum, por exemplo. Mas não obtive sucesso até o momento.

Colunas na tabela: `id`, `gid`, `nome`, `num_inicio_esquerda`, `num_fim_esquerda`, `num_inicio_direita`, `num_fim_direita`, `cep_esquerda`, `cep_direita`, `bairro_esquerda`, `bairro_direita`, `nivel_detalhamento`, `estado_nome`, `estado_sigla`, `cidade`, `latitude_inicio`, `latitude_fim`, `longitude_inicio`, `longitude_fim`.

- Index na coluna nome.

É possível fazer com que o banco não demore para dar a resposta quando não é encontrado um registro?

Exemplo de uma consulta realizada na tabela endereços:

```
select
      gid,
      bairro_esquerda,
      cep_direita,
      cep_esquerda,
      cidade,
      estado_nome,
      estado_sigla,
      latitude_fim,
      latitude_inicio,
      longitude_fim,
      longitude_inicio,
      nivel_detalhamento,
      nome,
      num_fim_direita,
      num_fim_esquerda,
      num_inicio_direita,
      num_inicio_esquerda 
  from
      enderecos
  where
      nome like 'avenida treze de maio'
      and (
          estado_sigla like 'CE'
      ) 
      and (
          lower(unaccent(cidade))='fortaleza'
      ) 
      and (
          cast(num_inicio_esquerda as integer)<=1116 
          and cast(num_fim_esquerda as integer)>=1116 
          or cast(num_fim_esquerda as integer)<=1116 
          and cast(num_inicio_esquerda as integer)>=1116 
          or cast(num_inicio_direita as integer)<=1116 
          and cast(num_fim_direita as integer)>=1116 
          or cast(num_fim_direita as integer)<=1116 
          and cast(num_inicio_direita as integer)>=1116
      ) limit 1
```

Comment: É possível, mas só conhecendo o problema em detalhes para ajudar. Normalmente a solução é criar índice. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32052/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55118/101

Comment: @Naldson Chagas: Depende muito da consulta que você está executando no banco de dados. Você poderia postar algum exemplo ?

Comment: Pessoal, consegui uma melhora significativa adicionando index em mais três colunas (nome, cidade, estado_sigla). @Lacobus: Postarei sim um exemplo de uma consulta.

Answer (score 2):

Não é recomendado o uso da cláusula `LIKE` para buscas textuais em tabelas com um grande volume de dados.

É recomendado o uso de um recurso do Postgres chamado [FTS (Full Text Search)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-intro.html).

Segue um passo-a-passo de como você poderá utiliza-lo a fim de melhorar a performance da sua consulta:

**1** - Criar uma coluna auxiliar `sv_nome` do tipo `tsvector` na tabela `enderecos`:

```
ALTER TABLE enderecos ADD COLUMN sv_nome tsvector;
```

**2** - Criar uma `TRIGGER` que seja disparada a cada `INSERT` e `UPDATE` na tabela `enderecos`, que será capaz de manter a coluna auxiliar sempre coesa:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fc_enderecos() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        new.sv_nome = to_tsvector('portuguese', COALESCE(NEW.nome, ''));
    END IF;

    IF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        IF NEW.nome <> OLD.nome THEN
            new.sv_nome = to_tsvector('portuguese', COALESCE(NEW.nome, ''));
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER trg_enderecos BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON enderecos FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fc_enderecos();
```

**3** - Criação do `INDEX` na coluna auxiliar criada no passo 1:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_enderecos_nome ON enderecos USING gin( to_tsvector('portuguese'::regconfig, COALESCE((sv_nome)::text, ''::text)));
```

**4** - Atualização dos dados já existentes na tabela:

```
UPDATE enderecos SET sv_nome = to_tsvector('portuguese', COALESCE(nome, ''));
```

**5** - E, finalmente, a sua consulta poderá ser feita da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT
    gid,
    bairro_esquerda,
    cep_direita,
    cep_esquerda,
    cidade,
    estado_nome,
    estado_sigla,
    latitude_fim,
    latitude_inicio,
    longitude_fim,
    longitude_inicio,
    nivel_detalhamento,
    nome,
    num_fim_direita,
    num_fim_esquerda,
    num_inicio_direita,
    num_inicio_esquerda 
FROM
    enderecos
WHERE
    sv_nome @@ public.to_tsquery('portuguese', 'avenida&treze&de&maio' ) AND
    and (
          estado_sigla = 'CE'
      ) 
      and (
          lower(unaccent(cidade))='fortaleza'
      ) 
      and (
          cast(num_inicio_esquerda as integer)<=1116 
          and cast(num_fim_esquerda as integer)>=1116 
          or cast(num_fim_esquerda as integer)<=1116 
          and cast(num_inicio_esquerda as integer)>=1116 
          or cast(num_inicio_direita as integer)<=1116 
          and cast(num_fim_direita as integer)>=1116 
          or cast(num_fim_direita as integer)<=1116 
          and cast(num_inicio_direita as integer)>=1116
      ) limit 1
```

Espero ter Ajudado!