# Consultas MYSQL fazendo Table Scan mesmo usando index key

Tags: mysql

Comecei recentemente a estudar performance das consultas no MYSQL, estou tentando utilizar EXPLAIN para ir analisando e melhorando os indexs das minhas tabelas, até que me deparei com a seguinte situação.

Estou fazendo uma consulta simples filtrando os usuários do dominio através do campo usuario_dominio, que é um index key.

Quando uso o valor 1 para selecionar os usuários pertencentes ao domínio 1, parece que não usa o index e  faz um table scan em todos os 9 registros da tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui, uso o valor 2 para selecionar os usuários pertencentes ao domínio 2, e nesse caso, parece que o index funciona corretamente e seleciona os registros diretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebi esse mesmo comportamento em algumas outras consultas, e um table scan não pode ocorrer de forma nenhuma devido o projeto ser um SaaS Multi-tenant, o que pode levar a consultas extremamente demoradas. Alguém tem noção do que possa ser?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, ainda estou tentando entender o porque de algumas consultas não estarem usando o index key. Acredito que ainda vai levar um tempo para analisar tudo melhor, porém, vou atualizando a resposta.

Primeira coisa que tentei foi forçar o uso do index com o USE INDEX(), porém o resultado foi o mesmo, o índice não foi usado.

Depois me veio na cabeça que poderia ser alguma coisa de errado nos primeiros registros, que eram antigos e cadastrados a muito tempo atrás. Resolvi então apagar o DB e inseri-lo novamente. Fiz 3 backups do DB, um com os dados e com as tabelas, um removendo os dados antigos e inserindo novos dados e tabelas e o terceiro somente com as tabelas, sem os dados. Nas 3 restaurações a consulta continuou a não usar o index key.

Percebi que em algumas outras consultas o index key também não era usado, e continuei pesquisando até que cheguei ao seguinte tópico: [Índices em consultas no MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32052/%C3%8Dndices-em-consultas-no-mysql)

No final da resposta o **Maniero** diz:

> Na verdade pode ser que o índice não seja usado mesmo que tenha uma chave adequada. Há volumes de dados pequenos que a busca direta nos dados tenha um custo menor. O otimizador pode identificar que mesmo que ele possa selecionar sub-faixas, a análise subsequente pode ser tão custosa que eliminando a consulta ao índice pode trazer um resultado melhor. Mas nestes casos o otimizador renunciou seu uso de forma "consciente" para o seu benefício. Não dá para achar ruim. Apesar que há casos que ele erra.

Acredito que possa ser o que está acontecendo comigo, pela quantidade de tuplas serem pequenas e não existirem muitos itens a serem filtrados, a consulta acaba abrindo mão do index key em algumas ocasiões, mas não em todas.