# Usando ElasticSearch para fazer buscas complexas e depois pegar os IDs para consulta ao MySQL

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

Estou pensando na seguinte ideia: Usar os recursos do ElasticSearch para fazer buscas complexas ao invés de fazer consultas diretas ao MySQL usando muitos `where`. Se eu fosse usar o MYSQL eu teria que criar muitos índices.

Então quando eu der um `insert` na minha tabela eu também vou por o registro no ElasticSearch, faria essa consulta complexa no ElasticSerch e pegaria os `id`'s para depois fazer uma consulta ao MySQL usando por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1,4,8,9,21,54,87,...)
```

Isso seria viável?

Comment: está utilizando alguma linguagem de programação no meio?

Comment: Sim, estou usando PHP, com framework Laravel 5.1

Comment: Você pode tentar então quebrar em duas partes sua lógica, na primeira parte fazer a consulta no Elastic e pelo Laravel usar o `whereIn` do Eloquent

Comment: gmsants, foi isso que falei na pergunta. Eu gostaria de saber se essa é uma boa abordagem, se valeria a pena fazer assim.

Comment: Acredito que sim. Não conheço muito bem o Elasticsearch ainda, pretendo estudar ele em algumas semanas. Por isso não me arrisco a deixar nenhuma resposta por enquanto.

Comment: Olha, me parece um grande desperdício de recursos. O Elastic Search já pode retornar tudo o que você precisa, você **não deve** fazer duas buscas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu utilizo dessa forma para fazer minhas consultar pois o a relevância e muito maior e mais rápida com os ids em mão eu faço a consulta no mysql para retornar um resultado:

```
WHERE produtos.id_produto IN (id1,id2,id...) 
ORDER BY FIELD(id1,id2,id...)
```

Utilize o `order by field` para você não perder a ordenação do score do elasticsearch.