# Subqueries podem diminuir a performance? Mito ou verdade?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, desempenho

Bem, costumo trabalhar apenas com *frameworks*. Eu trabalho com *frameworks* MVC e costumo utilizar os ORMs para fazer consulta ao banco de dados.

No meu caso eu utilizo Laravel, mas já usei outros *frameworks*, e tive a oportunidade recente de conhecer o Entity Framework.

Alguns usuários experientes quanto ao uso do Entity Framework me mostrou que o ORM do mesmo costuma gerar uma SQL para consulta diferente da que estamos acostumados (algo que alguém sismado demais poderia dizer que diminui a performance).

Da mesma forma já constatei isso no *framework* Laravel.

O que quero dizer é que, em alguns casos, esses *frameworks* costumam gerar algumas consultas com *subqueries*, ao invés de usar um `JOIN`.

Por exemplo, eu já vi uma *query* que, para identificar se um usuário possui alguma publicação, estava sendo gerada dessa forma:

```
select * from 
    usuarios 
where 
    (select count(*) from `posts` where `usuarios`.`id` = `posts`.`usuario_id`) >= 1
```

Mas creio que a mesma consulta poderia ser feito com JOIN.

Bem, agora eu explico por que estou falando dos *frameworks* antes de entrar no assunto. É porque já ouvi vários comentários da boca de "programadores", que dizem que *subqueries* causa problema de performance. Porém o que não dá pra entender é porque os *frameworks* então insistiriam em fazer algo que fosse prejudicial (diminuir a performance é prejudicial, quis dizer nesse contexto).

Porém, se vejo sendo usado  nos *frameworks*, logo vem à mente que "não tem problema nenhum" usar *subqueries*. E sem tem algum problema, não entenderia então o por quê de os desenvolvedores dos *frameworks*, que teoricamente teriam experiência suficiente para saber o que estão fazendo.

Eu um ISSUE no Github, onde havia alguém reportando o problema de performance por causa das *subqueries* geradas, observei que o desenvolvedor da biblioteca perguntou: "Mas as suas tabelas contém os índices definidos corretamente?", o que me levou a entender que o problema as vezes pode estar mais na maneira errada de usar do que propriamente na *subquery*.

Então, baseado em todos os meus argumentos acima, pergunto:

- *Subqueries* **sempre** causam problema de performance, ou pode ocorrer esse problema dependendo de um contexto específico?
- É verdade que a definição de índices para uma tabela pode melhorar o desempenho de uma *subquery* ou isso é baboseira?
- A consulta mostrara acima, no exemplo, se fosse feita de outra forma (como por exemplo, usando `JOIN`), teria melhoria de performance?

Comment: só um detalhe que não responde a sua pergunta, mas que contribui para você melhorá-la. O SQL mostrado não é um exemplo válido de subquery. Não há como fazer isso em SQL, pelo menos nos SGDBs que conheço.

Comment: Obrigado @cantoni, boa observação

Comment: Fiquei surpreso em saber que o laravel gera uma query "porca" dessas. Se eu quero saber publicações de um usuário faria apenas: SELECT COUNT(POST_ID) FROM POSTS WHERE PUBLISHER_ID = 100 por exemplo. Contaria por um campo só, reduzindo a quantidade de bytes por tupla eliminando obviamente o *. Não precisaria nem de join pois quero saber a quantidade de posts de usuários ativos e não ativos, qualquer coisa só passar um atributo a mais no where e tudo resolvido. Incrível como complicam aquilo que deveria ser tão simples!

Comment: Em relação aos frameworks (e a alguns projetos em OO que usam bastante OO) as vezes, manter o padrão não é o melhor caso de performance. Escrever orientado a objeto de forma a obter performance é por si só uma tarefa dificil. Muitas vezes, você tem um programador experiente que escreve um código pouco performantico por causa do Design ou da cultura. Um ponto importante em relação aos frameworks é que eles não tem como prever todas formas que serão usados, mas, tentam gerar código baseado em padrões de comportamento e boas práticas de design, logo, podem gerar código de baixa performance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Subqueries sempre causam problema de performance, ou pode ocorrer esse problema dependendo de um contexto específico?

"Sempre" é uma expressão muito pesada, depende muito do caso. E aí não só do código gerado, mas também depende do otimizador do banco de dados, a forma como a execução se dá, e é claro, do conjunto de dados e modelo que está trabalhando, e mais um fator que falo abaixo.

Tem que analisar cada caso, sempre tem que medir.

> É verdade que a definição de índices para uma tabela pode melhorar o desempenho de uma SubQuery ou isso é baboseira?

Total verdade, índices podem ser a salvação da lavoura se forem definidos corretamente. Esse pode ser o fator que realmente fará a diferença. Eles não podem salvar tudo e podem trazer alguns pequenos malefícios também (as atualizações ficam mais lentas, há mais consumo de espaço em disco e memória, etc.). Novamente, depende do que está fazendo e fornecedor usado.

- [Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do uso de índices em base de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101)
- [Como aplicar indexes para melhorar a performance das queries?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55118/101)
- [Índices desnecessários no banco são um problema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23348/101)
- [Use the index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)

> A consulta mostrara acima, no exemplo, se fosse feita de outra forma (como por exemplo, usando JOIN), teria melhoria de performance?

Esse exemplo especificamente eu não sei dizer, mas em exemplos mais comuns posso dizer que depende do banco de dados e como seria esse `JOIN`, em alguns pode ser que haja alguma otimização (bem comum). Em outros o `JOIN` é só açúcar sintático para a expressão comum.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: vc mitou... hehehe

Answer (score 6):

> SubQueries podem diminuir a performance?

Em resumo, podem. Mas não é sempre assim.

> Subqueries **sempre** causam problema de performance, ou pode ocorrer esse problema dependendo de um contexto específico?

Não. Tudo depende do motor de consulta do banco de dados e da estatística compilada em cima do esforço da consulta. Índices podem sim prejudicar o desempenho se mal formulados, mas a maior penalidade de desempenho normalmente vem de um *design* pobre de esquema de banco de dados.

Se o motor de banco de dados suporta executar *subqueries* em paralelo, o resultado pode até ser mais rápido que na execução usando *joins*. [Há farto questionamento disso até mesmo no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=joins+subqueries). O que responde adequadamente a isto é o estudo do plano de consulta. Cada banco de dados tem a sua maneira de obter este estudo.

> É verdade que a definição de índices para uma tabela pode melhorar o desempenho de uma SubQuery ou isso é baboseira?

É verdade, dependendo do banco em que estamos falando. No Oracle, por exemplo, [um `TABLE SCAN` pode ser mais rápido que uma busca por índices](http://www.davidclement.org/tipsntrx/tnt5.3.html).

Novamente, vale a pena aplicar o índice e estudar a sentença.

> A consulta mostrada acima, no exemplo, se fosse feita de outra forma (como por exemplo, usando JOIN), teria melhoria de performance?

E mais uma vez, depende. No SQL Server, por exemplo, [normalmente JOINS são mais rápidos que *subqueries*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052596/subquery-v-s-inner-join-in-sql-server), mas isto pode variar.

[Aqui há um artigo sobre como obter o plano de execução da sua consulta no SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/).

Answer (score 5):

Wallace, isto vai dependendo muito da engine do Banco de Dados, tendo como exemplo as duas consultas abaixo:

```
--Query A
SELECT 
    A.TabelaAID,
    A.Descricao as DescricaoA
    (SELECT Descricao FROM TabelaB B WHERE A.TabelaBID = B.TabelaBID) as DescricaoB,
    (SELECT Descricao FROM TabelaC C WHERE A.TabelaBID = C.TabelaBID) as DescricaoC,
    (SELECT Descricao FROM TabelaD D WHERE A.TabelaBID = D.TabelaBID) as DescricaoD
FROM TabelaA A

--Query B
SELECT 
    A.TabelaAID,
    A.Descricao as DescricaoA
    B.Descricao as DescricaoB,
    C.Descricao as DescricaoC,
    D.Descricao as DescricaoD
FROM TabelaA A
LEFT JOIN TabelaB B ON A.TabelaBID = B.TabelaBID
LEFT JOIN TabelaC C ON A.TabelaBID = C.TabelaBID
LEFT JOIN TabelaD D ON A.TabelaBID = D.TabelaBID
```

No `SqlServer 2005` a `Query A` era exponencialmente mais lenta que a `Query B`, isto tudo por que a engine não conseguia traduzir a `subquery` em um `join`. como resultado, caso a TabelaA tivesse 1000 registros, a `Query A` iria executar 3001 consultas e a `Query B` apenas 1.

No `SqlServer 2014`, ainda existem algumas diferenças de desempenho, mas nada extraordinario, dependendo da consulta a `subquery` vai ser até mais rápido que o `join`.

Agora quanto ao seu exemplo, acredito que teria um melhor desempenho se usa-se `EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM post WHERE post.usuario_id = usuarios.id)` ao invés de um `COUNT` com `*`.

O seguinte artigo possui uma ótima comparação que envolve uma tipo particular de subquery, que é bastante semelhante à do seu exemplo:

[Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: Toby, o seu comentário sobre trocar Exists por Count é interessante. Recentemente, notei que o Framework Laravel substituiu o SELECT do meu Exemplo para um semelhante ao que você fez (usou o Exists)