# Tem como melhorar estes 12 selects onde só varia um parâmetro?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, select

tenho uma tabela online com uns 3 mil registros. faço doze selects pra listar os resultados por mes, ex:

```
select count(campo) from tabela where extract(year from data) = 2016 and extract(month from data) = 1;
select count(campo) from tabela where extract(year from data) = 2016 and extract(month from data) = 2;
select count(campo) from tabela where extract(year from data) = 2016 and extract(month from data) = 3;
```

uso PHP e quero saber se é viável fazer assim:

```
select * from tabela where extract(year from data) = 2016;
select count(campo) from RESULTADO_ANTERIOR extract(month from data) = 1;
select count(campo) from RESULTADO_ANTERIOR extract(month from data) = 2;
select count(campo) from RESULTADO_ANTERIOR extract(month from data) = 3;
```

se for melhor fazer assim, podem me dar um exemplo de como fazer?

obs: a tabela vai ficar bem maior quando eu acrescentar outros dados que tenho, pois sao dados de 2006 até hoje.

**edit**
o relatório deve listar todos os nascidos vivos em um ano específico, ex:

```
         JAN|FEV|MAR|ABR|MAI|JUN|JUL|AGO|SET|OUT|NOV|DEZ
FEMININO  1 | 3 | 5 | 18| 3 | 2 | 4 | 45| 34| 4 | 34| 23
MASCULINO 1 | 3 | 5 | 18| 3 | 4 | 4 | 45| 34| 4 | 34| 23
MENOR 2KG 1 | 3 | 5 | 18| 3 | 2 | 4 | 45| 34| 4 | 34| 23
MAIOR 2KG 1 | 3 | 5 | 18| 3 | 2 | 4 | 45| 34| 4 | 34| 23
HOSPITAL  1 | 3 | 5 | 18| 3 | 2 | 4 | 45| 34| 4 | 34| 23
OUTROS    1 | 3 | 5 | 18| 3 | 2 | 4 | 45| 34| 4 | 34| 23
MAE <18ANO1 | 3 | 5 | 18| 3 | 2 | 4 | 45| 34| 4 | 34| 23
MAR >18ANO1 | 3 | 5 | 18| 3 | 2 | 4 | 45| 34| 4 | 34| 23
```

espero que dê pra entender. do jeito que faço atualmente, calculo cada campo indivualmente utilizando estruturas de repeticao alterando os meses, mas tá demorando muito :/

abraços.

Comment: Relacionada: [Subqueries podem diminuir a performance? Mito ou verdade?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138334/91). Não sei a finalidade dessa consulta mas tenho a impressão que agrupar o resultado por ano e mês resolveria.

Comment: tenho que listar todos os nascidos vivos em um ano específico e por categoria, vou postar exemplo na pergunta

Comment: Isso me parece caso para um simples `GROUP BY`. Aliás,  esse extract é estranho, qual seria o motivo de não usar `YEAR( data )` e `MONTH( data )` ? Me dá impressão de estar usando tipo de campo errado para precisar disso.

Comment: estou tentando agrupar aqui, caso consiga, posto o resultado

Comment: `where extract(year from data) = 2016 GROUP BY extract(month from data)`

Comment: @Bacco funcionou sim ^^, só mais um detalhe pra resolver: os meses novembro e dezembro que ainda não nasceu ninguém, não aparece o número 0, tem como fazer pra aparecer?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo não faz sentido aparecer coisa que não existe. Até tem como criar uma situação com SQL, mas desnecessariamente complexa, Muito mais fácil fazer um for( $mes  contando de 1 a 12 no PHP mesmo, e mostrar zero onde não tiver resultado. Essas coisas compensa controlar na exibição.

Comment: não sabia que era possível agrupar usando extract ^^

Comment: Eu acho estranho é estar usando extract :) - normalmente eu usaria MONTH( data );

Comment: @Bacco posso até contornar isso com o PHP, mas caso o mês em branco esteja no meio, ex: só nasceu em janeiro e em março. como eu sei que nao nasceu em fevereiro? tem uma forma de mostrar o mes?

Comment: não conhecia o comando year(data) e month(data), pois adaptei o código de um banco firebird

Comment: Só incluir no retorno. COUNT(*), MONTH( data ) AS mes FROM ..., ai no PHP você usa o $row['mes'] como índice do array, para usar no o loop de 1 a 12.

Comment: massa, consegui resolver aqui. você ajudou bastante. como eu faço pra selecionar sua resposta como escolhida? o código final ficou assim: select count(nu), month(data) from sinasc where year(data) = "2016" and municipio_ibge = "260500" group by month(data)

Comment: O problema, Italo, é que sua pergunta ficou completamente diferente do modo que removemos, por isso resolvi nos comentários e não como resposta oficial. Se quiser, você pode postar no campo abaixo a sua solução final, sem problemas.

Comment: sou novato aqui, o que devo fazer então pra finalizar?

Comment: Pode postar o código final como resposta no campo abaixo , e marque como aceita se quiser.

Comment: Umas dicas de leitura pra aproveitar melhor o site: [Ask], [O que é o problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499) e [FAQ da Comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/699)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido com a ajuda de Bacco. o código final ficou assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total, MONTH(data) mes 
FROM tabela
WHERE YEAR(data) =  "2016"
GROUP BY MONTH(data)
```

Não precisei usar um select dentro de outro, dessa forma ficou muito mais rápido.

Comment: Depois você pode clicar no V verdinho do lado da sua resposta, para marcar como sendo a solução aceita, assim, futuros visitantes verão já na listagem da página principal que foi resolvida.