# SQL + Left Join

Tags: sql

Tenho 3 tabelas `produto`, `carrinhoProduto` e `venda` eu queria saber  os produtos que não se venderam no ano `2015`:

```
SELECT p.idProduto,p.descricao as 'Produto',datepart(year,v.dataVenda) as 'Ano'
FROM Venda v
INNER JOIN CarrinhoProduto cp ON v.idCarrinho = cp.idCarrinho
LEFT JOIN Produto p ON p.idProduto = cp.idProduto
WHERE cp.idProduto IS NULL AND datepart(year,GETDATE()) = 2015
GROUP BY p.idProduto, p.descricao, v.dataVenda
```

O resultado é todos os produtos que não se venderam, isto é, de sempre 2016+2015+....etc., mas apenas queria os de 2015.

Comment: Qual exatamente é o tipo do seu campo de data na tabela?

Comment: Boas, o tipo é date

Comment: @Dexter qual o banco de dados que você está utilizando?

Answer (score 2):

Se o seu campo é um `date`, basta filtrar com um operador simples:

```
SELECT p.idProduto, p.descricao as 'Produto', YEAR(v.dataVenda) as 'Ano'
FROM Produto p
LEFT JOIN Venda v ON p.idProduto = cp.idProduto
LEFT JOIN CarrinhoProduto cp ON v.idCarrinho = cp.idCarrinho
WHERE YEAR(v.dataVenda) <> 2015 OR v.dataVenda IS NULL
GROUP BY p.idProduto, v.dataVenda
```

Ou ainda utilizando um `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT p.idProduto, p.descricao as 'Produto', YEAR(v.dataVenda) as 'Ano'
FROM Produto p
LEFT JOIN Venda v ON p.idProduto = cp.idProduto
LEFT JOIN CarrinhoProduto cp ON v.idCarrinho = cp.idCarrinho
WHERE YEAR(v.dataVenda) NOT BETWEEN 2015 AND 2015 OR v.dataVenda IS NULL
GROUP BY p.idProduto, v.dataVenda
```

Neste caso, o ideal é que sua tabela principal(`FROM`), seja `Produto` ao invés de `Venda`, o que consequentemente muda a ordem dos `JOIN`s da sua consulta, depois disso a primeira condição (em ambas as consultas) garante você não trará produtos vendidos no ano da filtragem e a segunda condição, garante que você trará também produtos que nunca foram vendidos. Removi também o `p.descricao` do `group by`, já que você já está agrupando por `p.idProduto`.

Comment: Também tentei assim e não funciona, alias nem mostra nada, mas se tirar o where cp.idProduto IS NULL  e deixar so where YEAR(v.dataVenda) = 2015 ele mostra os produtos mas o resultado esta mal

Comment: @Dexter, editei a minha resposta! =)

Answer (score 1):

Na realidade a melhor forma seria com `NOT EXISTS` já que a cláusula existe exatamente para esta finalidade:

```
SELECT p.idProduto,
       p.descricao AS 'Produto',
       2015 AS 'Ano'
  FROM Produto p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT
                    FROM Venda v
                         INNER JOIN CarrinhoProduto cp ON v.idCarrinho = cp.idCarrinho
                   WHERE cp.idProduto = p.idProduto
                     AND DATEPART(YEAR, v.dataVenda) = 2015)
```

*Observação:* como o ano é definido em uma variável, provavelmente não é interessante retorná-lo nesta `query`.

---

> [`EXISTS`](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php)
>
> The SQL EXISTS condition is used in combination with a subquery and is considered to be met, if the subquery returns at least one row.

Em tradução livre:

> A condição EXISTS da SQL é usada em conjunto com uma subquery e é considerada como cumprida se  a subquery retornar pelo menos uma linha.

Comment: O problema é que a data esta na tabela venda, por isso esta solução nao funciona.

Obrigado

Comment: @Dexter você há de concordar que não faz sentido você pegar uma informação da tabela de venda sendo que você está procurando algo que não deve estar lá

Comment: Eu tenho a seguinte logica,
Produto-i
dProduto int not null identity(1,1),
 descricao varchar(120) not null,
 idCategoria tinyint not null,
 precoUnitario decimal(6,2) not null,
 promocao int null,

CarrinhoProd tenho id carrinho e idProd e a quantidade.
depois em venda tenho id venda,idFuncionario, idCarrinho, datavenda etc

Comment: Particularmente eu não gosto de soluções com subquery, independente de funcionar, elas devem ser evitadas por questões de performance.

Comment: @KennyRafael Se mal utilizadas afetam a performance mesmo. Quanto a esse caso, qualquer solução sem subquery vai tornar o resultado dependente de haver uma venda. Se vc tentar um ano que não existe venda nenhum resultado irá aparecer já que tem um inner join com venda e isso está completamente incorreto. Sugiro que você leia a resposta dessa pergunta: [Subqueries podem diminuir a performance? Mito ou verdade?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138334/subqueries-podem-diminuir-a-performance-mito-ou-verdade)

Comment: Só me ocorre solução por NOT EXISTS ou NOT IN e existem pesquisas em que o resultado é mais importante que a eficiência , vai rodar uma vez e pronto.

Comment: @Sorack, é para isso que exite o `left join`.

Comment: @KennyRafael O `LEFT JOIN`serve pra trazer informações a esquerda mesmo que não haja a direita. No caso, não deve depender da vendas. A solução com `LEFT` neste caso é falha, pois apresenta o problema que expliquei no meu último comentário.

Comment: @Sorack, o `left join` se utiliza perfeitamente nesse caso justamente por isso, filtrando o `ano` como fiz na minha resposta, basta adicionar mais um `where` onde o resultado da direita justamente não exista, visto que ele precisa saber o que NÃO vendeu naquele ano...

Comment: @KennyRafael você faz um `FROM` na tabela `vendas`, nunca trará nenhum resultado em um ano que ainda não teve venda.

Comment: @Sorack, muito obrigado, apesar de seu equívoco com relação a utilização do `LEFT JOIN` nesta questão, você me fez perceber que estava tratando errado a regra de negócio do @Dexter, de toda forma, creio que você se prendeu de mais a isso (regra de negócio), e não compreendeu o que o recurso poderia oferecer. Espero que entenda como uma crítica construtiva, pois ambas as soluções funcionam, não há a necessidade de se matar por isso.

Comment: @KennyRafael tranquilo, eu também não tenho intenção de te ofender, tudo que eu falei foi como crítica construtiva também e sem intuito de agredir de forma alguma