# Mysql - Qual o melhor indice a ser criado neste caso

Tags: mysql, desempenho, índices

Ola,

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados com o historico de preços de produtos. Esta tabela é muito volumosa tendo mais de 1 bilhao de registros.

Como eu posso criar um indice nesta tabela, para atender a query abaixo:

```
select 
    cd_produto_price,
    min(vlr_produto) as vlr_produto 
from 
    preco_produto_fornecedor 
where 
    dt_atualizacao < date(now()) 
and vlr_produto > 0 
group by 
    cd_produto_price;
```

Possiveis indices:

1. Somente o campo dt_atualizacao
2. Somente o campo vlr_produto
3. Campos dt_atualizacao, vlr_produto
4. Campos dt_atualizacao, vlr_produto e cd_produto
5. Alguma outra opção?

Obs.: Preciso criar o indice certo, pois a base ja esta muito grande (espaco em disco)

Comment: É difícil ter certeza sem conhecer os dados prováveis que estará na tabela. O que pode parecer bom na teoria pode não ser na prática. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32052/101. Em muitos casos a coluna usada para agrupar costuma ser uma boa ideia. Mas dependendo de como ela vai interagir com o filtro pode ficar complicado. A princípio eu ficaria entre alguma variação do item 4. A melhor forma de saber qual é o melhor índice é criando eles e testando. Isso vale para cada banco de dados,versão e padrão de dados atual.Se criar índice demais pode ter problemas:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23348/101

Comment: Me parece o caso de repensar na arquitetura. Neste volume de dados não é muito normal ficar trabalhando na tabela de histórico, e sim criar uma agregação intermediária.

Comment: ola bacco.. eu ja possuo uma outra tabela onde mantenho a informcao mais atual do preco. porem, tenho uma funcionalidade de historico, onde o usuario pode acompanhar todos os precos dos ultimos 30 dias.. e 1 preco por semana caso o prazo for superior a 30 dias. Ja excluo os registros que nao interessam.

Comment: bigown, eu tinha um indice somente pela coluna valor (item 2), mas alem deste tinham varios outros indices e o tamanho do banco ja nao estava mais cabendo no HD. Eliminei todos, mantive o indice principal e esta tudo certo. So faltou o indice para atender essa query onde o indice principal, nao atende.

enviar o tipo de cada campo ajuda em algo?