# Consultas mais pesadas no MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Como saber quais as consultas estão sendo mais pesadas no meu bd mysql? Tem algum comando que eu possa dar que vai me trazer esses dados?

Comment: Só como referência, em inglês, não traduzi ainda: *Identifying MySQL Slow Queries*

Comment: Provavelmente isto responde, se não acho que a pergunta é ampla ou não clara: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32052/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55118/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23348/101.

Comment: >https://www.isbrasil.info/blog/como-medir-as-consultas-do-seu-mysql-e-evitar-lentidao.html neste link é possível ver diversos testes que dá pra realizar no seu db, boa sorte. =)

Comment: @J.AugustoLima isso ai é mais sobre estrutura do banco do que a questão de queries (***consultas***), o caso do autor acho que é mais para querys mesmo, claro que o link é util, afinal não adianta querer resolver tudo na query e não ter uma estrutura bem planejada de suas tabelas e até configurações no my.ini e servidor.