# Vale a pena colocar duas chaves estrangeiras numa tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql, chave-estrangeira

tendo as tabelas:

1. Empresas
2. Clientes

   - empresa_id: chave estrangeira
3. Vendas

   - cliente_id: chave estrangeira

sendo que as relações são:

- Empresas e Clientes => 1:N
- Clientes e Vendas => 1:N

Considerando que irei precisar listar todas as vendas da empresa, vale a pena criar uma segunda chave estrangeira na tabela vendas para que eu possa fazer:

```
SELECT * FROM `vendas` WHERE `empresa_id` = 'x'
```

Comment: Depende da necessidade do projeto. Se você precisar filtrar as vendas por empresas, deve colocar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela descrição deve usar sim, mas não é certo. Precisa da performance? Uma coisa que eu vejo muito em relatórios é não precisar, mas depende do caso. Quanto mais índices coloca mais lento fica para atualizar as tabelas e isso pode ser crítico em certos ambientes.

É perfeitamente possível fazer sem ter a chave estrangeira, mas fazer um `JOIN` sem ela pode tornar tudo muito mais lento.

É uma questão de medição. Você faz e mede e vê se compensa ou não para a sua necessidade.

Veja:

- [Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do uso de índices em base de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101)
- [Índices desnecessários no banco são um problema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23348/101)
- [Índices em consultas no MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32052/101)

Comment: Ainda não tive tempo de ler os artigos que me passou, mas após sua resposta, fiz alguns testes e optei pelo uso da chave extra, pois a tabela vendas terá um volume de informações absurdo e logo desempenho será uma prioridade.

Answer (score -1):

Tendo em conta que já existe uma chave estrangeira `empresa_id` na tabela `Clientes` e uma venda pressupõe **sempre** um cliente (através do campo `cliente_id`, suponho que seja `NOT NULL`), não será necessário criar uma chave estrangeira para a empresa na tabela `Vendas`. Aliás, duplicação de informação (assim como de código) nunca é boa prática.

Como já foi referido, a consulta `SQL` para filtrar por empresa é simples:

```
SELECT      * 
FROM        Vendas      V
INNER JOIN  Clientes    C ON V.cliente_id = C.id 
WHERE       C.empresa_id = 'X'
```

Comment: Ao meu ver esse "nunca é uma boa prática" ficou fora de contexto. Se a minha consulta levar 1 minuto para finalizar com o JOIN, mas levaria 10 segundos se possuísse a chave estrangeira e eu preciso que seja o mais rápido possível, não seria uma *boa prática* eu otimizar com a chave estrangeira?

Comment: Isso que eu estava pensando @AndersonCarlosWoss, pois a tabela vendas irá receber TODAS as vendas de TODAS as empresas... irá crescer muito rápido e uma hora o desempenho vai ser um requisito.