# Desenvolvimento multi-camadas e regra de negócios

Tags: sql, delphi, postgresql, webserver, multi-tenancy

Trabalho com uma equipe desenvolvendo um ERP e estou responsável por emissão de relatórios, da qual um deles executa um `select` no banco que em testes chegou a levar mais de 2h rodando, o que acarretou erros e uma grande duvida: "quem estava processando toda a informação?" E foi aí que começou o problema pois o processamento não é feito pela aplicação servidora (web server) mas pelo banco de dados (neste caso o PostgreSQL).

O correto é realizar todos os possíveis cálculos diretamente na consulta do SQL (vendo que todas as funções para cálculos se encontram no próprio banco de dados) ou apenas buscar os dados primitivos do banco e realizar toda a operação via código pela camada servidora?

Se tiverem referências é de suma importância.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende. Se os dados estão todos no banco de dados e faz sentido executar lá para dar resultados menores, é relativamente simples fazê-los, então deve fazer lá, caso contrário, se o mais importante for pegar os dados brutos onde todos serão necessários no relatório, os cálculos são secundários então deve fazer na aplicação.

Não tem mágica, não tem receita de bolo. Eu sei que hoje em dia muitas pessoas que trabalham em TI acham que é só decorar algumas regras, algumas soluções e tudo se resolve. Se isso fosse verdade estaríamos começando a ficar sem empregos em breve. Para saber a resposta certa disto depende de muita experiência, conhecimento profundo da computação e entender todos os detalhes do contexto para dar uma resposta definitiva. Na verdade nem tão definitiva, apenas enquanto durarem os mesmos critérios e volumes.

Não é questão de onde se faz, mas como se faz. É quase certo que não deveria levar 21 horas, muito provavelmente está sendo feito de forma errada e a solução correta não é decidir em que lugar fazer, é fazer levar menos tempo. Aí tem uma série de técnicas para reduzir este tempo, precisa analisar a(s) consulta(s) para descobrir onde estão ocorrendo gargalos, e aí entendendo o funcionamento do banco de dados, mudar as consultas, as configurações para atender a demanda deste caso, sem atrapalhar outros casos. É simples? Claro que não, por isso temos empregos e ganhamos bem.

Pelo que está dizendo parece que nem fará diferença onde está rodando, mas pode ser uma especulação errada minha pela falta de informações da pergunta.

Só lembrando que cálculo em si costuma ser uma ínfima parte do processamento, o padrão de acesso aos dados costuma ser bem pior, especialmente me relatórios.

Em alguns casos o hardware disponível não é adequado e causa extrema lentidão.

Existem métodos científicos de observar as ocorrências para isolar o problema, eliminar as interferências, focar no problema específica e achar a causa raiz, mas isso é um escopo geral e não de desenvolvimento ou operação de infraestrutura.

Em alguns casos é culpa da modelagem existente. O que mais ocorre é as pessoas não entenderem [o poder do índice](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101) (em outros o problema é [o abuso deles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23348/101)).

Comment: Estou de total acordo, desculpe-me pela falta de informações. Realmente não são questões simples e provavelmente a possível solução é temporária. 
O Caso estou realizando um relatório de Posição de estoque validando, lote, produto, deposito, estoque, tudo ramificada em N's tabelas. Consegui encontrar informações desnecessárias entre joins nas tabelas da qual reduziu bastante o tempo, mas não o suficiente. A questão mesmo era sobre o processamento, já que por algum motivo a qry que está sendo processada (independente do tempo) toma 1 núcleo inteiro do processador (Um servidor dedicado). Obg.

Comment: Tente rodar um EXPLAIN ANALYZE em sua consulta para verificar eventuais gargalos e possíveis faltas de índices em suas tabelas.